# Restrict Shipping Class by specific Zipcodes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, geo

I'm trying to find a more manageable way to restrict shipping class to specific zipcode.

My configuration as below:

---

**Shipping method**: Self Collect, Free Delivery, Delivery with a fee
**Shipping Class**: Class A, Class B, Class C
**Shipping Country**: Only 1 country
**Shipping Zone**: Zone A, Subset of Zone A (specific Zipcode 123*)
**Shipping plugin:** Table Rate Shipping

---

**Conditions:**
All shipping methods are applicable to Class A, B and C. Class C is restricted to zipcode 123* only. If orders contain Class C and shipping address is outside of zipcode 123*, the shipping method will be defaulted to self-collect only.

I figure I can set up two zones. One zone contains specifically zipcode 123*. And setup another zone manually inserting every other zipcodes excluding zipcode 123*. I find this approach onerous and difficult to maintain considering it doesn't support import and export natively.

I wonder if there is a way to restrict class to specific zipcodes only? I only managed to restrict product categories by countries but can't find a way to restrict by zipcodes.

Comment: What exactly is your question, and what have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @HowardE Thanks. `to restrict shipping class to specific zipcodes only` Didn't manage to solvle it other than the thought of manually inserting the zipcodes. I can't find any ID for zipcodes nor shipping class to query it like countries. Any thoughts?